# How can i check if user sign's out from games services default view?

Tags: android, google-plus, securityexception, google-play-games

I integrated google games services in my game, including Leaderboards and achievements. If the user opens the leaderboard or achievement activity, he has the possibility to sign out from the settings in the right upper corner.

How can I check if the user is actually signed in? getGamesClient.isConnected() is still true, although the user logged out from the google view.

If I'm clicking the logout button (which is still there, becaus gamesClient is still connected) I get an SecurityException:

08-16 11:01:21.262  14288-14288/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.SecurityException
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.bm$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.bj.signOut(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.games.GamesClient.signOut(Unknown Source)

At the moment, I am checking the ActivityForResult response code and disconnecting the GamesClient, if it's in inconsistent state, but I don't like that approach.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try handling onActivityResult:

```
public boolean onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == RC_YOUR_UNIQUE_ID 
            && resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
        mHelper.disconnect();
        // update your logic here (show login btn, hide logout btn).            
    } else {
        mHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    return false;
}
```

RC_YOUR_UNIQUE_ID is id you've used for showing Leaderboard or Achievements activity.

Comment: This should be updated to `mHelper.disconnect()`. Thanks for this answer, helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is: isSignedIn();
Like this:

```
    public boolean getSignedIn() {
    return isSignedIn();
}
```

This is will return a true or false if user is signed or not.
The method in GameHelper.java:

```
    /** Returns whether or not the user is signed in. */
public boolean isSignedIn() {
    return mState == STATE_CONNECTED;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The Problem is, that I (or rather the GameHelper) set the mState, for example in onStop() or in signOut(). But if the user signs out from the Leaderboard Activity settings, which is provided by google, nothing like signOut() happens, hence, the mState variable doesn't change and even gives a wrong state, because it indicates, I'm signed in but I'm not.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am doing as following. On `MainActivity` ovveride `onActivityResult()`.  `RC_UNUSED` is the `requestCode` when you call to open `Leaderboards`, `Achievements` and `Settings` activity from Google Play service app.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
if (requestCode == RC_UNUSED 
&& resultCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
        signOut();
    }

    Log.i("test", "On Activity result called");
}
```

Write your `signOut()` method as following

```
public void signOut() {
    try {
        Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
    }catch (SecurityException se){
        Log.i("test", "mGoogleApiClient status was disconnected when callin signOut status. message = " + se.getMessage());
    }
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    // update your UI logic here (show login btn, hide logout btn).
}
```

Don't forget to update your UI on the end of `signOut()`