# How to detect sign out via the Google Play Leaderboards UI?

Tags: android, google-play-games

Signing out or disconnecting the GamesClient is straightforward when it is from your own UI, such as a button on the main menu.

However, users can also sign out from the game from the Google Play UI in the acheivements and leaderboard views displayed by the intents such as getAllLeaderboardsIntent().  (It's a bit hidden, but if you tap the menu in the upper right, it lets you sign out.)

There are a few promising listener interfaces like OnSignOutCompleteListener but they don't seem to work with a sign out via the google UI, only from your own UI calling GamesClient.signOut().

How can I detect that the user has signed out from the leaderboards or achievement intents?  Is it possible to have a callback for this?

I want to be able to update my in-game UI to reflect the logged-in status.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i check if user sign's out from games services default view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271874/how-can-i-check-if-user-signs-out-from-games-services-default-view)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately GameHelper doesn't detect when you logout from Google play games.

What you need to do is to put this in your onActivityResult() method in your activity.

I encounter a crash error when I tried using aHelper.signOut() when res == RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED is true.

Instead I created a resetAllValues() method which resets back all values to its default in GameHelper.

In my MainActivity.java

```
protected void onActivityResult(int req, int res, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(req, res, data);

    if (res == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED) {
        aHelper.resetAllValues();
    } else {
        aHelper.onActivityResult(req, res, data);
    }
}
```

My method in GameHelper.java

```
public void resetAllValues()
{
    mProgressDialog = null;
    mAutoSignIn = true;
    mUserInitiatedSignIn = false;
    mConnectionResult = null;
    mSignInError = false;
    mExpectingActivityResult = false;
    mSignedIn = false;
    mDebugLog = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate from:

[How can i check if user sign's out from games services default view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271874/how-can-i-check-if-user-signs-out-from-games-services-default-view)

As I see it, there is no elegant solution to that. You can check the response_code in onActivityResult for INCONSISTENT_STATE and cut off the GamesClient, but I'm not sure, if you can potetially get to an inconsistent state in any other manner...