# Play Games: Is there a GameHelper.signOut() listener?

Tags: android, google-play-games

How can I know if the **GameHelper.signOut()** request is successful in the Google Play Games API?

The documentation does not tell how to use the **[OnSignOutCompleteListener](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/api/com/google/android/gms/games/OnSignOutCompleteListener)** where in the API should I set this listener? And is it actually the right listener for the GameHelper.signOut() method.

*PS: I'm not looking for the method described in this (different) question:
[How can i check if user sign's out from games services default view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271874/how-can-i-check-if-user-signs-out-from-games-services-default-view) because I'm not launching a default Play Games view (Activity).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Games.signOut()` returns a [`PendingResult<Status>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.html) object on which you can set a `ResultCallback` via `setResultCallback()`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the source code for the GamesClient is packed in a jar with .class files, can't edit the source hence. I also found that the GameHelper is not calling the GamesClient.signOut() method as you suggested but the Games.singOut() method. which is another thing. Source: // For the games client, signing out means calling signOut and
        // disconnecting
        if (0 != (mRequestedClients & CLIENT_GAMES)) {
            debugLog("Signing out from the Google API Client.");
            Games.signOut(mGoogleApiClient);
        }

Comment: `Games.signOut()` returns a `PendingResult<Status>` (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/PendingResult.html) object on which you can set a `ResultCallback` via `setResultCallback()`

Comment: You should change your answer, your comment is the actual solution!